# Dead Code Elimination (DCE) Not Working with LLVM Opt

Tags: clang, llvm

I'm having trouble with Dead Code Elimination (DCE) when using LLVM's opt tool. I have a simple C program as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 10;
    int c = a + b;
    return 0;
}
```

I compile this program to LLVM IR using the following command:

```bash
clang -S -emit-llvm main.c -o main.ll
```

Then, I attempt to perform Dead Code Elimination using opt with the following command:

```bash
opt -O2 -adce main.ll -o main_optimized.ll
```

```
; ModuleID = 'main.ll'
source_filename = "main.c"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-p270:32:32-p271:32:32-p272:64:64-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable
define dso_local i32 @main() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca i32, align 4
  %3 = alloca i32, align 4
  %4 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
  store i32 5, i32* %2, align 4
  store i32 10, i32* %3, align 4
  %5 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
  %6 = load i32, i32* %3, align 4
  %7 = add nsw i32 %5, %6
  store i32 %7, i32* %4, align 4
  ret i32 0
}

attributes #0 = { noinline nounwind optnone uwtable "frame-pointer"="all" "min-legal-vector-width"="0" "no-trapping-math"="true" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+cx8,+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "tune-cpu"="generic" }

!llvm.module.flags = !{!0, !1, !2, !3, !4}
!llvm.ident = !{!5}

!0 = !{i32 1, !"wchar_size", i32 4}
!1 = !{i32 7, !"PIC Level", i32 2}
!2 = !{i32 7, !"PIE Level", i32 2}
!3 = !{i32 7, !"uwtable", i32 1}
!4 = !{i32 7, !"frame-pointer", i32 2}
!5 = !{!"Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1"}
```

The problem is that main_optimized.ll ends up containing the same content as main.ll, indicating that no optimization has occurred. I'm wondering why the optimization is not working as expected.

Steps Taken to Troubleshoot:

- I tried different optimization levels (-O1, -O3) with the same result.
- I verified that the code in main.ll contains dead code that should be eliminated.

Questions:

1. Why is Dead Code Elimination not working as expected in this case?
2. Are there any specific considerations when using opt for Dead Code Elimination with LLVM IR?
   I appreciate any insights or suggestions to help resolve this issue. Thank you!

detail
OS:6.2.0-34-generic #34~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep  7 13:12:03 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

LLVM Version : 14.0.0

Clang version :
Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin

Command Line:
fish+tmux

Answer (score 1):

Your function has an `optnone` attribute:

```
; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable
```

that disables all further optimizations.

You'd need either remove it manually or run clang something like this:

```
clang -O2 -Xclang -disable-llvm-passes
```